# Problema al modificar el icono de la pestaña en React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

- Buenas, tengo un problema al modificar el icono de la pestaña de una pagina hecha en react, en el `index.html` tengo el siguiente codigo ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Slab:ital,wght@0,700;1,700&family=Noto+Sans+Mono:wght@900&family=Quicksand:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">  
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fauna+One&family=Josefin+Slab:ital,wght@0,700;1,700&family=Noto+Sans+Mono:wght@900&family=Quicksand:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/>
    <title>Weder</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Y en la carpeta `public` de la pagina, tengo un archivo `favicon.ico`, ademas borre los archivos de los iconos de react que vienen por defecto al usar `npx create-react-app ...` .

A pesar de todo esto, la pagina sigue mostrando el icono por defecto de react. Que tengo que hacer?

Comment: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">` en esta linea ya probaste poner el icono que deseas que salga? ese favicon.ico apunta hacia el icono que React trae por defecto

Comment: Esos iconos normalmente se almacenan en caché por el navegador o por los service worker. Intenta eliminar la caché. Sino, a veces funciona ponerle algo distinto en la url... por ejemplo `href="./favicon.ico?a=1"` para que lo tome como un icono distinto

Comment: El icono que vas a agregar también agrégalo en la misma ruta o sea en ***public*** y ya luego modificas el `href` buscando el icono que vas a poner